# Do I need to roll the lawn?

Tags: lawn

My backyard has a turf since 2 years ago, when this model home has been built. However, I think the lawn has not been rolled, as when I walk around the soil is very loose, which I think has led to a very improper growth of the lawn. Do I need to roll it now in the spring and does it work after 2 years? If so, does a 200lb hand roller work? any more idea?

Comment: This is a question I've never even considered.  Where is  it that you live? Warm or  cool season grasses.  I am very into 'rolling' or compacting a lawn bed so that it doesn't develop dips and hills and so that there is good seed/soil contact.  My initial response would be YES.  If  a 'roller' could squish out the dips and hills that would be nice.  Never, have I ever heard about doing this or have done this.  Sounds quick and easy but not once did I even consider this.  How much of your lawn is like  this, send a picture please.  Very interesting question!

Comment: We need also information about ground/soil. If it is very humid, you need to drain the terrain, or the rolling will only temporarily compact the soil.I would have also some extra soil/sand to add when rolling, to better even the lawn. This to raise the soil and the roots of grass, not to cover it, so this should be done in various "rounds".

Comment: We need pictures please - it is not usual to roll lawns when they have been in place a while, unless its a bowling green or cricket table. If the turf had not rooted properly, it would be dead, not 'loose' so its not clear what you mean